# Getting frequency counts of items in a list

Tags: python

This most likely has been asked before but I can't seem to find a straight forward solution. Say I have a bunch of numbers in a list like:

```
1234
2233
3232
1234
```

I need to find a way to print the frequency total for the items in the list using a script, so something like this:

```
1234 2
2233 1
3232 1
```

Can someone shed some light on this for me?

Thank you

Comment: Use `collections.Counter`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
l = [1234,2233,3232,1234]
c = Counter(l)
print c
```

Outputs:

```
Counter({1234: 2, 3232: 1, 2233: 1})
```

---

Explanation:

This utilizes the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). It returns a `dict` like object (technically, `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`). This means that you can do something like:

```
print c[1234]
```

and get a result of

```
2
```

---

Another option you have, if you aren't looking for a dictionary like object, is to build a list of tuples that contains the value/count pairs.

```
zip(Counter(l).keys(), Counter(l).values())
```

This returns something like this:

```
[(3232, 1), (2233, 1), (1234, 2)]
```

---

The Counter class was added in Python 2.7. Based on the error you posted to another answer, it seems you are using 2.6 or older. You can either upgrade to 2.7, or you can utilize the [backport](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/) of the Counter class.

You could also use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and count the items:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [1234,2233,3232,1234]
d = defaultdict(int)

for curr in l:
    d[curr] += 1

print d
```

`d` is a dictionary that looks like this:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {3232: 1, 2233: 1, 1234: 2})
```

You can access this the same way you would with the `Counter`:

```
d[1234]
```

prints

```
2
```

Comment: Is there a way other than using counter that is supported by my version?

Comment: @Russ, I've updated the end of my answer to include information on utilizing `defaultdict` from the `collections` module. This was introduced in 2.5

Answer (score 3):

You can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: my_list = [1,3,3,2]

In [3]: Counter(my_list)
Out[3]: Counter({3: 2, 1: 1, 2: 1})
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get an error saying "cannot import name Counter"

Comment: @Russ, what version of `python` are you using? If I recall correctly `Counter` was added in `2.7`, so if you have an earlier version, that could be why.

Comment: @Russ Is your error similar to this one?: `ImportError: cannot import name Counter`

Comment: Yep, as you and @Andy have said, I have version 2.6 so that's why it's producing the error

Answer (score 1):

The code below

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [
    1234,
    2233,
    3232,
    1234
]
print [(key, len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby(sorted(a))]
```

Will give you:

> [(1234, 2), (2233, 1), (3232, 1)]